# 5 Brothers, what are we?

Tags: riddle

> I have 4 brothers
> My 1st brother is a bother, and points everything out
> My 2nd brother is tall, and quite foul at heart.
> My 3rd brother is about as tall as my 1st, and quite decorative.
> My 4th brother is short and skinny, but among the strongest of us all.
> I am short and squat and weak, but am by far the most useful.

What are we?

(Hint: This is too easy for a hint, I think. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are

> the five fingers of a hand

My 1st brother is a bother, and points everything out

> The index is used to point at something

My 2nd brother is tall, and quite foul at heart.

> The middle finger is usually the longest
>  (sorry, as a non-native speaker, I did not understand "foul at heart", is that an idiom?)

My 3rd brother is about as tall as my 1st, and quite decorative.

> The ring finger is often as long as the index and carry all sorts of rings

My 4th brother is short and skinny, but among the strongest of us all.

> The thumb is the shortest but the strongest of all five

I am short and squat and weak, but am by far the most useful.

> You are pinky, the most useful for you owner's ears

Update: below are some corrections by the OP to my initial answer.

> The 4th brother is the pinky, short and skinny, but among three of the strongest fingers of the hand. The narrator is the thumb, short and squat, but most useful because the opposing thumb allows us to grasp things.

Comment: The main idea is right! But you got some of the fingers mixed up. Pay close attention to the size description of the fingers.

Comment: Also, the middle finger is used as a curse word nowadays(not that I use it that way.)

Comment: @AndroidWonKenobi Thanks for your help. I must admit I hesitated between the 4th brother and the one that "speaks" and I may have mixed up the two, but "the strongest of us all" lead me to the present choice. I re-read my answer and can hardly come with something else. For "foul at heart", sorry, I just don't understand the meaning of this. Does this mean "impetuous"?

Comment: That's fine! The "foul at heart" is just a little pointer to the fact that people raise their middle as a curse word. Probably better you didn't know that XD. The 4th brother is the pinky, short and skinny, but among three of the strongest fingers of the hand. The narrator is the thumb, short and squat, but most useful because the opposing thumb allows us to grasp things.

Comment: @AndroidWonKenobi Thanks for the explanation. I added it to my answer. As for the curse word, I guess it is quite international and we have the same ;-) The issue is just that I don't know what "foul at heart" means, thus I'm unable to bring any explanation about why it's related to that curse word.

Comment: XD That's alright! "foul at heart" simply implied the vulgar use of the middle finger as a curse word, that's all.